# Rack: launching the proc from a standalone file

Tags: ruby, rack

I'd like to launch a simple proc from a standalone file:

```
# config.ru
require 'rack'
require File.expand_path '../app.rb', __FILE__
run @app

# app.rb
@app = Proc.new do |env| 
  [
    200,
    {'Content-Type'=> 'text/html'},
    ["<head><title>My app</title></head><body>Hello world</body>"]
  ]
end
```

But this causes the scope issue - the @app var, seems, is not visible inside the config.ru. Therefore the following is appeared inside the error log `Message from application: missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)` How do I handle this?

Comment: You could encapsulate the proc in a method defined within a module, and then call the module method ?

Comment: @Sam, yeap. it works!

Comment: Great :) Can you put your approach and accept your own answer, so this Q is marked resolved please.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is using the method, provided by the module, rather than the instantce var:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# app.rb
module AppModule
  def self.start_app
    Proc.new do |env| 
      [
        200,
        {'Content-Type'=> 'text/html'},
        ["<head><title>ENV VARS</title></head><body>#{ENV.sort.each {|k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}"}}</body>"]
      ]
    end
  end
end

# config.ru
require 'rack'
require File.expand_path '../app.rb', __FILE__
run AppModule.start_app
```